# How to stop booting of Linux kernel(3.14) if sensor is not able to probe in u-boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I ported ADXL345(accelerometer) on AM335x SOC successfully.In mux.c file in u-boot i did changes so that to communicate properly.
But I in case the communication fails, I want kernel not to boot.

please help me in this, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your board file, in board_init function add the check for the accelerometer and see if communicates and on failure return -EINVAL, so you board doesnt boot up at all.

Comment: @TusharNimkar Your board file might look something like this:  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-at91/board-1arm.c?v=3.14  Make changes in your platform-specific file.

Comment: @TusharNimkar If you look at line 542 in the link http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=board/ti/am335x/board.c;h=111ed3556cc3c603107e796209c23ea7399b3873;hb=refs/heads/master  there is board_ini() function just before return 0; statement add your check for the accelerometer if it fails return -EINVAL on success return 0; This will make sure it wont boot into Linux.